# New site is loading Under Construction page instead of Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress

I created my first online site. I put all my files on the server (I used Wordpress for now) and it's great, but, when I enter my site address (let's say: www.mysite.com) I see only "Under construction". I only see my website after typing: www.mysite.com/index.php.

How can I make www.mysite.com load index.php without needing to enter it in the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an index.html file at the root of your public html folder that you need to delete. Once you delete this, your site will load as normal.

Most web servers load .html files before any other files. So if you have index.html and index.php in the root of your public html folder, it will most likely load index.html first.

You also may need to make sure you have an `.htaccess` file in the root of your public html folder, and that it contains the basic Wordpress code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

More info on that [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess).

Comment: There was indeed index.html (from the website service provider) and index.php (wordpress). I deleted the first one, and still the same problem

Comment: If you remove index.html, it should fix your issue. Or if you just want to rename it to save it for later, name it anything other than index.html.

Comment: I did remove it and still nothing.

Comment: I've added an additional fix that will probably work for you, read my updated answer.

Comment: The htaccess is in the root of my public html folder and it contains the code you wrote. But still - same problem. What about something like adding DirectoryIndex index.php -- what is it about?

Comment: Just confirming that it's actually named `.htaccess` and not `htaccess`.

Comment: Confirming - .htaccess it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100722/discussion-between-corey-and-ancinek).